# Java 8 Cucumber After and Before using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, cucumber

I using Java 8 with cucumber. It's possible to create lambda expression for Given, When, Then, And, But e.g.

`When("test", (String path) -> this.driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)));`

My question is is it possible to create lambda expression form After and Before instead of `@Before("@scenarioTest")` or `@After("@scenarioTest")`?

Comment: Could you please show us what kind of lambda you have in mind there? What do you want to *express* using lambdas? And for the record: you understand what lambdas are, and what these annotations and their parameters **mean**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use After/Before without tags you can use

```
After(()->{
    YOUR_CODE;
});
```

or if you want to pass tags you can do it passing table like this:

```
String[] tags = {"@tag1", "@tag2"};
Before(tags, ()->YOUR_CODE);
```